# Joint Density $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ where $Y=g(X)$, $g$ is monotone decreasing

Tags: joint-distribution

**Question**

Let $X$ be a random variable and $Y=g(X)$, where $g$ is a monotone decreasing function. Then I want to find the joint cumulative density $$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X\leq x, Y \leq y)=P(X\leq x, g(X)\leq y).$$

I reasoned as follows but got stuck:

Suppose $g(x)<y$. If we knew that $Y>y$ then we would know that $g(X)>g(x)$ so $X<x$.

Now I try the same reasoning with $g(x)>y$ and $X>x$ known but it breaks down.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $g$ is monotone decreasing, it is also invertible.  This means we can transform all statements about $y$ into statements about $x$ by running them through $g^{-1}$, as $x = g^{-1}(y)$ - remembering, as I failed to do, that the monotone decreasing nature of $g$ means inequality signs will be reversed by the transform!

Doing this with your first line results in (and thanks to the OP for correcting my mistake here!):

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X\leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X\leq x, X\geq g^{-1}(y))$$

If $x \leq g^{-1}(y)$, $P(X\leq x, X\geq g^{-1}(y)) = 0$.

On the other hand, if $x > g^{-1}(y)$, $P(X\leq x, X\geq g^{-1}(y)) = P(x\leq x) - P(x < g^{-1}(y))$.